# How do I test to see if a doc exists based off of a date field?

Tags: meteor

I have a Template helper that attempting to return the current "Day" from the database. What's happening is that even though the current day or date exists in the database, for some reason my helper doesn't see that and creates another date.

client:

```
Template.days.helpers({
   day: function() {
      console.log("day called");
      var now = new Date();
      var month = now.getUTCMonth();
      var day = now.getUTCDate();
      var year = now.getUTCFullYear();
      var bottomRangeDate = new Date(year, month, day);
      var topRangeDate = new Date(year, month, day + 1);
      // console.log('bottomRangeDate', bottomRangeDate);
      // console.log('topRangeDate', topRangeDate);

      var currentDay = Days.findOne({"date": {"$gte": bottomRangeDate, "$lt": topRangeDate }});
      // console.log(currentDay);
      if (currentDay !== undefined) {
         // console.log("current day exists");
         Session.set('currentDayId', currentDay._id);

         return currentDay;
      } else {
         // console.log('current day is undefined');
         Meteor.call('createDay', now, function(error, result) {
            if(!error)
               Session.set('currentDayId', result);
         });
         // console.log("current day does not exist");
      }
   }
});
```

server:

```
Meteor.methods({
   createDay: function(date) {
      console.log("date ", date);
      var dayId = Days.insert({
                     date: date
                  });
      return dayId;
   }
});
```

So what I need to do is to see if today or "date" exists in the database, and if it does return it. If does not, I need to create it.

**Edit**
Here's a screen shot console after refreshing the browser and call `find().fetch()` on the collection.

[image]

**Edit #2**
I changed the code up a little to try and get it to work with moment:

```
Template.days.helpers({
   day: function() {

      var bottomRangeDate = moment().startOf('day').toDate();
      var topRangeDate = moment().endOf('day').toDate();
      var now = new Date();
      console.log('bottomRangeDate: ', bottomRangeDate);
      console.log('topRangeDate: ', topRangeDate);

      var currentDay = Days.findOne({"date": {"$gte": bottomRangeDate, "$lt": topRangeDate }});

      if (currentDay !== undefined) {
         Session.set('currentDayId', currentDay._id);
         return currentDay;
      } else {
         Meteor.call('createDay', now, function(error, result) {
            if(!error) {
               Session.set('currentDayId', result);
               return Days.findOne({_id: result });
            }
         });
      }
   }

});
```

I'm still getting duplicates:

[image]

Comment: are you sure you don't need to also set the time in your bottom and top to midnight? Maybe show the document in the database you would like to find, and then show us the values of your top and bottom.

Comment: @ChristianFritz I just added a screen shot that shows the logging of the bottom and top date range variables and also the Days collection.

Comment: Looks like the potential for a race condition here. The template could render multiple times and end up calling `day` twice which will in turn call the method twice. Maybe on the server side check that a date does not exist for that day prior to insertion. In general I wouldn't advise doing inserts in a helper like this - much safer is to do them after an event.

Comment: @DavidWeldon When you say after an event, do you think that the rendered callback would be a better place?

Comment: @DavidWeldon I think I just answered my own question. I altered that code to just check if that day does not exists, and I placed that code in the rendered callback and in my server method. It works.

Comment: Cool, I'm glad you got it working. :) You may want to put it in the [created](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_created) callback instead of `rendered`. Before v0.8, `rendered` will still potentially be called multiple times.